# Python. Метод не видит переменных в классе

Tags: python, классы

Всем привет. Я только начал изучать классы и решил переделать под них текстовый квест. Только вот теперь функция kamera больше не хочет видеть переменные и выдает ошибку. Подскажите, насколько сильно я дурак)

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self, pc, s, u):
        self.pc = pc
        self.s = s
        self.u = u
        pc = 0
        s = 0
        u = 0
    def kamera(self): #ПЕРВАЯ ГЛАВА
        print ("\nОсвободившись " +
        "от оков, вы осмотрелись: в небольшой камере находились" + "\n|стол|, |дверь камеры|, |угол камеры|")
        choise = input(">")
        if choise == "стол":
            print("")
            if s == 0:
                pc += 1
                print("Подойдя к практически сгнившему деревянному столу" +
            "вы обнаружили, что на нем лежит пыльная кожанная записная книжка.")
                s += 1
                kamera(self)
            else:
                print ("На столе больше нет ничего интересного")
                kamera(self)
        elif choise == "угол камеры":
            if u == 0:
                pc += 1
                print ("вы подошли к углу камеры и нашли там ключ")
                u += 1
                kamera(self)
            else:
                print ("вы подошли к углу камеры, но не нашли там ничего интересного")
                kamera(self)
        elif choise == "дверь камеры":
            if pc == 2:
                print ("вы вставили ключ в замок и вышли из камеры")
                print("выбравшись из камеры, вы очутились в коридоре.")
                koridor()
            else:
                print("вы подошли к двери камеры, но поняли, что что-то упустили")
                kamera(self)
Game.kamera()
```

Comment: место `s`, `ps`, `u` пишите `self.s`, `self.pc`, `self.u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

место `s`, `ps`, `u` пишите `self.s`, `self.pc`, `self.u`.

Место `Game.camera` пишите `Game(0, 0, 0).camera()`

Место `camera(self)`, `koridor()` пишите `self.camera()`, `self.koridor()`

Comment: исправил, как вы написали, но теперь компилятор ругается на Game().kamera() Просит вписать 3 аргумента под скобки Game, но когда я это делаю он их не распознает и пишет "NameError: name 'pc' is not defined". (пытался и просто pc, s, u и self.pc...)

Comment: @groupiks готово